# org-mode structure templates only someone works

Tags: org-mode, template

I want to use [structure templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html) with tab but only: `<c` `<e` `<q` `<v` work.

(With `emacs -Q` no templates work.)

Comment: Are you doing `(require 'org-tempo)` somewhere in your init file?

Comment: That was a hint: try doing `(require 'org-tempo)` in your init file and see if that helps. See [Structure Templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: Correct, thanks!